# Flutter Widgets to Image file

Tags: flutter, image, dart, invoice, flutter-widget

I am creating a project where an image receipt will be generated for a use which he can download to device or share to people.

I don't know if it is possible to design a page in flutter then convert it to image.

Comment: Can you share your progress, some code, what have you tried so far? This question needs a lot of focus and show progress in order to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) library..

Comment: nice. can you direct me on how to save it in folder

Comment: this link may helps you.. https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot#saving-images-to-gallery